# Numpy element-wise addition with multiple arrays

Tags: numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I'd like to know if there is a more efficient/pythonic way to add multiple numpy arrays (2D) rather than:

```py
def sum_multiple_arrays(list_of_arrays):
   a = np.zeros(shape=list_of_arrays[0].shape) #initialize array of 0s
   for array in list_of_arrays:
      a += array
   return a
```

Ps: I am aware of  `np.add()` but it works only with 2 arrays.

Comment: `np.sum(list_of_arrays, axis=0)` should work.  Or `np.add.reduce(list_of_arrays)`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please let it be an answer so i can accept

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
np.sum(list_of_arrays, axis=0)
```

should work. Or

```
np.add.reduce(list_of_arrays).
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest most Pythonic solution is simply to use `sum()`, like so:

```py
sum(list_of_arrays)
```

Comment: doesnt work for more than 2 arrays.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Seems to work for me, for example: `sum([np.array([0,1]), np.array([1,0]), np.array([1.1, 1.1])])`

Answer (score 1):

i know the question says numpy, but here's a pure python answer in case someone needs it.

`map(sum, zip(a,b))`
which returns a generator.
you can also do `list(map(sum, zip(a,b)))` to get a list