# Numpy arrays addition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray

I have 4 different numpy arrays with 40 values in each and i want to add all the elements at position 0 of 4 arrays together and store in another array at loc 0. All the elements at location 1 and store in location 1 and same for all 40 elements of 4 arrays . How should I do in python?

Comment: it would be good if you can give an example of what you want, it seems to me you want to simply add 4 arrays

Comment: no minimum effor code example, poor explanation, no research done.

Comment: Using numpy, it should be as simple as `a + b`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy element-wise addition with multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111665/numpy-element-wise-addition-with-multiple-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do some study on [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

> NumPy operations are usually done on pairs of arrays on an
> element-by-element basis. In the simplest case, the two arrays must
> have exactly the same shape,

From your question it seems you are in the simplest use case, like the following:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(4)
arr+arr*arr+arr

#array([ 0,  3,  8, 15])
```

multiple operations on array of the same shape

Comment: OP just wants to do element-wise addition between 4 arrays...

Comment: The example do exactly this, apply different operation element-wise on 4 array